# tsql select query by time from and time to

Tags: t-sql

I need to have a select query where the query is filtered by time format like this.

From: 7:00 AM
To: 8:00 AM

for example:

```
DECLARE @TimeFrom varchar(7)
DECLARE @TimeTo varchar(7)
DECLARE @StartDate varchar(10)
DECLARE @EndDate varchar(10)


SET @TimeFrom = '7:00 AM'
SET @TimeTo = '8:00 AM'
SET @StartDate = '05/07/2014'
SET @EndDate = '05/07/2014'

SELECT *
FROM [Call]
WHERE LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),StartTime,100),7)) BETWEEN @TimeFrom AND @TimeTo
and CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 101) = '05/07/2014'
AND SubDispositionID LIKE ('SA%')
ORDER BY StartTime ASC
```

The problem with this query is I am also getting data from 7:00 PM to 8:00 PM.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you compare STRINGS so `7:00 PM` is between `7:00 AM` AND `8:00 AM`

I think you should avoid 'AM\PM' and use 24h notation:

```
SET @TimeFrom = '07:00'
SET @TimeTo = '08:00'
....
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(5),StartTime,108) BETWEEN @TimeFrom AND @TimeTo
```

Here is conversion to `VARCHAR(5)` to cut seconds from time string.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @valex. I think I got it. I'll post what I got and you may comment on it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   DECLARE @TimeFrom varchar(7)
DECLARE @TimeTo varchar(7)
DECLARE @StartDate varchar(10)
DECLARE @EndDate varchar(10)


SET @TimeFrom = '7:00 AM'
SET @TimeTo = '8:00 AM'
SET @StartDate = '05/07/2014'
SET @EndDate = '05/07/2014'

SELECT *
FROM [Call]
WHERE CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 108) BETWEEN (select CONVERT(varchar(8), cast(@TimeFrom as datetime), 108))
AND (select convert(varchar(8), cast(@TimeTo as datetime), 108))
and CONVERT(VARCHAR, StartTime, 101) = '05/07/2014'
AND SubDispositionID LIKE ('SA%')
ORDER BY StartTime ASC
```